# Pandas remove rows only where NaN and float 0.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where each column represents a user.  I am trying to eliminate a any column that has nothing but NaN's and 0.000000's. So that the that username 1 or the first column would not be included in the dataframe, but the others would be.

This is the dataframe:

```
  username  1         2        3         4          5    
      date
2019-01-16  NaN       9.16667  NaN       NaN        1.000000
2019-01-17  NaN       NaN      NaN       1.000000   1.000000
2019-01-18  NaN       1.00000  0.956522  1.000000   1.000000
2019-01-19  0.000000  NaN      1.000000  NaN        NaN  
2019-01-20  0.000000  NaN      0.961538  NaN        NaN
```

The Percentages are stored as float64:

```
type(df['1'].iloc[0])
numpy.float64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start by replacing `0` by `NaN` and then drop columns which contain only `NaNs`:

```
df.loc[:,~df.replace(0,np.nan).isna().all()]

username            2         3    4    5
0        date      NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN
1  2019-01-16  9.16667       NaN  NaN  1.0
2  2019-01-17      NaN       NaN  1.0  1.0
3  2019-01-18  1.00000  0.956522  1.0  1.0
4  2019-01-19      NaN  1.000000  NaN  NaN
5  2019-01-20      NaN  0.961538  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert `0` values to `NaN` via [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and then [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.mask(df.eq(0)).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

This does convert `0` values to `NaN` even for non-deleted columns. It's not clear whether this is what you want, but probably advisable for consistency.